# Machine Learning Prediction with Probability and Target Value displayed

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, prediction

I created a multi-classifying SVC model that, based on text, classifies the input text to one of ~100 target values.

I have managed to display the Predict_proba:

Output:

```
array([[0.050, 0.001, 0.002, 0.701, 0.032, 0.008, 0.002, 0.001, 0.002,
        0.003, 0.005, 0.001 .... ]])
```

However, I also want the output to display just what target variable it belongs to. I also want it to output the target variable with the highest probability first. It might end up looking something like this:

Output: `Target4: 0.701, Target1: 0.050, Target5: 0.032` etc.....

How can I make this happen?

It would also be wonderful to only display the top 10 predicted target values (So I don't get outputs consisting of the probability of the ~100 target values).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `sklearn` you can try this snippet to print a lists of the top `N` classes and their corresponding probabilities:

```
print(sorted(zip(clf.classes_, probs[0]), key=lambda x:x[1])[-N:])
```